# How to change key in json by replacing @ with null string javascript

Tags: javascript, wso2-esb

In the below given JSON, I want to replace all the key elements with @ by null string.

```
{
    "AssetParams": [
        {
            "@DisplayName": "Device-ID",
            "@LiveUpdate": "false",
            "@MinLength": "1",
            "@Category": "IoT",
            "@Decoding": "none",
            "@xpath": "'Unit-ID''",
            "@ParamName": "Device-ID",
            "@Mandatory": "true",
            "@ReadOnly": "true",
            "@DataType": "String"
        },
        {
            "@DisplayName": "Device Host",
            "@DefaultValue": "",
            "@Category": "IoT",
            "@Decoding": "none",
            "@ParamName": "deviceHost",
            "@Mandatory": "false",
            "@ReadOnly": "false",
            "@DataType": "String"
}
]
}
```

result should be like:{"AssetParams":{ {
            "DisplayName": "Device-ID",
            "LiveUpdate": "false",
              ......},
             {
            "DisplayName": "Device Host",
            "DefaultValue": "",
           ....
               }
              ]
               }

Comment: W h a t have you tried?

Comment: i am new to javascript that's why i don't know what to do still searching , please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your input data, if we assume the `@` are only in the keys you can use the code below. Otherwise for a more general solution which updates only the keys, see @brk's answer.

```
var processed = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj).replace(/@/g, ""));
console.log(processed);
```

```js
     var obj = {
            "AssetParams": [
                {
                    "@DisplayName": "Device-ID",
                    "@LiveUpdate": "false",
                    "@MinLength": "1",
                    "@Category": "IoT",
                    "@Decoding": "none",
                    "@xpath": "'Unit-ID''",
                    "@ParamName": "Device-ID",
                    "@Mandatory": "true",
                    "@ReadOnly": "true",
                    "@DataType": "String"
                },
                {
                    "@DisplayName": "Device Host",
                    "@DefaultValue": "",
                    "@Category": "IoT",
                    "@Decoding": "none",
                    "@ParamName": "deviceHost",
                    "@Mandatory": "false",
                    "@ReadOnly": "false",
                    "@DataType": "String"
                }
            ]
        }

        var processed = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj).replace(/@/g, ""));
        console.log(processed);
```

Comment: Nice -  the is actually the better answer since the OP gave an object and not a string. Love the simplicity.

Comment: @RandyCasburn this will also remove `@` from values.Check this https://jsfiddle.net/meegpzmk/
the expectation is to remove `@` only from keys **replace all the key elements with @**

Comment: Yep. Good catch. @AliSharabiani you should capture everything prior to the `:` in the string.

Comment: @brk - we should put your answer and this answer (once corrected) on jsperf just for fun :-)

Comment: Yea @brk's answer is better, I assumed all the key's are marked with `@` and not the values.

Answer (score 2):

You can do a simple regex replacement (if your input JSON string is always guarantee to be this format. If not (for example, space between the right `"` and `:` for property names [Edit: this has been fixed]), you can tweak the following code a bit). This is definitely not the best solution in theory (we could do `JSON.parse` and loop through key value pairs, do insert and delete, and stringify later on), but it should be the fastest and shortest to write

```js
let jsonString = `
{
    "AssetParams": [
        {
            "@DisplayName"  : "Device-ID",
            "@LiveUpdate": "false",
            "@MinLength": "1",
            "@Category": "IoT",
            "@Decoding": "none",
            "@xpath": "'Unit-ID''",
            "@ParamName": "Device-ID",
            "@Mandatory": "true",
            "@ReadOnly": "true",
            "@DataType": "String"
        },
        {
            "@DisplayName": "Device Host",
            "@DefaultValue": "",
            "@Category": "IoT",
            "@Decoding": "none",
            "@ParamName": "deviceHost",
            "@Mandatory": "false",
            "@ReadOnly": "false",
            "@DataType": "String"
}
]
}
`
console.log(jsonString.replace(/"@([^"]*)"[\t\s]*:/g, '"$1":'))
```

Comment: The OP didn't provide a string. You should stringify it first. As Ali did in his answer. But I did upvote your answer because of the simplicity. Nice.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the array and then iterate over the keys. Replace the remove @ if present at start.

```js
let object = {
    "AssetParams": [
        {
            "@DisplayName": "Device-ID",
            "@LiveUpdate": "false",
            "@MinLength": "1",
            "@Category": "IoT",
            "@Decoding": "none",
            "@xpath": "'Unit-ID''",
            "@ParamName": "Device-ID",
            "@Mandatory": "true",
            "@ReadOnly": "true",
            "@DataType": "String"
        },
        {
            "@DisplayName": "Device Host",
            "@DefaultValue": "",
            "@Category": "IoT",
            "@Decoding": "none",
            "@ParamName": "deviceHost",
            "@Mandatory": "false",
            "@ReadOnly": "false",
            "@DataType": "String"
}
]
};

object.AssetParams.map( asset => {
  Object.keys(asset).map(key => {
     let value = asset[key];
     if(key[0] == '@') {
       let oldKey = key;
       asset[key.slice(1)] = value;
       delete asset[oldKey]
     }
  });
})

console.log(object)
```

Comment: Too complicated. but valiant effort. Don't forget that `for in` will iterate each key individually.

Answer (score 1):

Use string replace and array map method

```js
var obj = {
  "AssetParams": [{
      "@DisplayName": "Device-ID",
      "@LiveUpdate": "false",
      "@MinLength": "1",
      "@Category": "IoT",
      "@Decoding": "none",
      "@xpath": "'Unit-ID''",
      "@ParamName": "Device-ID",
      "@Mandatory": "true",
      "@ReadOnly": "true",
      "@DataType": "String"
    },
    {
      "@DisplayName": "Device Host",
      "@DefaultValue": "",
      "@Category": "IoT",
      "@Decoding": "none",
      "@ParamName": "deviceHost",
      "@Mandatory": "false",
      "@ReadOnly": "false",
      "@DataType": "String"
    }
  ]
}
// looping over the object
for (let keys in obj) {
   //checking if the current key's value is an array
  if (Array.isArray(obj[keys])) {
    // using map function to return a new array of modified values
    var x = obj[keys].map(function(item) {
      let newObj = {};
      for (let itemKeys in item) {
        // using string replace to remove the @
        newObj[itemKeys.replace('@', '')] = item[itemKeys];
      }
      return newObj

    })
    var modObj = {};
    modObj[keys] = x;
  }
  console.log(modObj);

}
```

Comment: Too complicated.